# R's as.numeric function in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numeric

I just started to translate a program from `R` to `python` and now i need a function in python, that does the same like the `as.numeric` function in `R`, but i have no idea yet.

At first i created a sequence with `numpy` and a dataframe with indices of half-open bins with `pandas`:

```
breaks = np.arange(0.0, 1.05, 0.05);
cut = pd.cut(data, breaks, right=False);
```

so i have something like that:

```
[1] [0.5,0.55) [0.6,0.65) [0.6,0.65) [0.6,0.65) [0.5,0.55) [0.55,0.6) [0.6,0.65) [0.6,0.65) [0.6,0.65)
```

now i want to give them a number like this (same indices get the same numbers):

```
[1] 11 13 13 13 11 12 13 13 13
```

How i can do it in `python`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cut.codes` should do the trick. It returns the category codes, similar to factor index levels on R.